# Why is my flex div not showing children in a row - and CSS is not applied?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a reactjs app using a flexbox div container that holds a few images inside of child divs.  Though I set the className on the outer div and the style includes display: flex, and flexDirection: row, the divs are displaying vertically.  I have added a bunch of other styles to try to test whether my styles are applied at all and it appears they are not applied at all.  If I rename the style const name, flexStyle, to something else, such as abc, I get an error from the div line that the flexStyle is not found so I know the style constant is scoped properly.

I have a minimal code sandbox instance of the code at https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-cannon-b1yhr

Any ideas why my styles are not applied?

Answer (score 0):

ClassName is for adding actual classes like in pure html class ="". See [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html) here. For inline styles you should use style ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style)) prop like so

```
<div style={flexStyle}>
   ....
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the docs references.  I copied code that I wrote that works successfully using className so the references help to figure out the difference.